# Product listed as “Allow Backorder” but showing as “In Stock”

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stock

I have products on my site that I would like to display as “On Order”

I’ve listed the items as “Allow Backorder” but still showing as “In Stock” and when I lower stock threshold it displays as “Out of Stock”.

Is there a way when an item is listed as Backorder to display custom availability? Example: Instead of “Out of Stock” display “On Order – Please allow 2 to 3 weeks for delivery”?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into the woocommerce_get_availability to change the text "Out of Stock".

Please try this code in your function.php file.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_availability', 'availability_on_order');
function availability_on_order($availability){
    $availability['availability'] = str_ireplace('Out of stock', 'On Order', $availability['availability']);
    return $availability;
}
```

As for the backorders - did you tick the checkbox for "enable stock management at product level?

Added 2nd script as comments can't format.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2); 
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) { 
   // Change In Stock Text 
   if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) { $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce'); } 
   // Change Out of Stock Text 
   if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) { $availability['availability'] = __('On Order', 'woocommerce'); } 
   return $availability; 
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the code, but unfortunately it's still showing as "Out of Stock". The "enable stock management at product level" is ticked also.

Comment: Can you post the link to where the text is?

Comment: Here's the link. Pass is brownhangers - https://creativeglams.com/product/bride-robe-set-2

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
    
    // Change In Stock Text
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('Available!', 'woocommerce');
    }
    // Change Out of Stock Text
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('On Order', 'woocommerce');
    }
    return $availability;
}

Comment: Remove the Available part if you don't want to change that.

Comment: I'm getting tbe following error - Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 695 of file /functions.php. Please fix and try saving again. syntax error, unexpectes end of file.

Comment: I inserted ankther curly bracket after ('Available!', 'woocommerce()) ;}} and it saved but still showing out of stock after that removed the comments  "//" and the syntax error returns. This is the first time using php.

Comment: I have added the script to my answer. You should not need to add any curly brackets.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Didn't realise you edited the answer. I've pasted it in the function.php and it saved, but still nothing changed even the wording when it's in stock it still shows In Stock instead of Available. I'm attaching images of the settings I'm using. https://imgur.com/5h2mi5c https://imgur.com/AclFeH1